# Rails - NameError - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nameerror

I get for what is this error, but I can't see a mistake in my code.
A controller is plural, a model is singular and the table name is plural.

Error on visiting index:

> NameError at /admin/custom_communities uninitialized constant
>   Admin::CustomCommunitiesController::CustomCommunity

**Generated controller:** (file: controllers/admin/custom_communities_controller.rb)

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Admin::CustomCommunitiesController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :set_custom_community, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @custom_communities = CustomCommunity.page(params[:page])
  end

  def show; end

  def new
    @custom_community = CustomCommunity.new
  end


  def edit; end


  def create
    @custom_community = CustomCommunity.new(custom_community_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @custom_community.save
        format.html { redirect_to @custom_community, notice: "Custom community was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @custom_community }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @custom_community.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @custom_community.update(custom_community_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @custom_community, notice: "Custom community was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @custom_community }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @custom_community.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @custom_community.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_custom_communities_url, notice: "Custom community was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_custom_community
      @custom_community = CustomCommunity.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def custom_community_params
      params.require(:custom_community).permit(:name, :description, :picture, :should_delete_picture)
    end
end
```

**Model:** (file: models/custom_community.rb)

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class CustomCommunity < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**Migration:**

```
class CreateCustomCommunities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :custom_communities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Routes:**
in admin routes:

```
resources :custom_communities
```

Comment: i changed the name of the model and now, i try to avoid the Plural/singular pattern of naming convention. less moving parts, better it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone else can explain why, but there are times rails will think that the following class in the index method:

```
class Admin::CustomCommunitiesController < Admin::BaseController
  def index
    CustomCommunity.all
  end
end
```

Is referencing a class defined within the `Admin::CustomCommunitiesController`, i.e. it thinks you're trying to call `Admin::CustomCommunitiesController::CustomCommunity.all`. To 'unnamespace' the class, try:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Admin::CustomCommunitiesController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :set_custom_community, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @custom_communities = ::CustomCommunity.page(params[:page])
  end

  def show; end

  def new
    @custom_community = ::CustomCommunity.new
  end


  def edit; end


  def create
    @custom_community = ::CustomCommunity.new(custom_community_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @custom_community.save
        format.html { redirect_to @custom_community, notice: "Custom community was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @custom_community }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @custom_community.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @custom_community.update(custom_community_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @custom_community, notice: "Custom community was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @custom_community }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @custom_community.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @custom_community.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_custom_communities_url, notice: "Custom community was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_custom_community
      @custom_community = ::CustomCommunity.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def custom_community_params
      params.require(:custom_community).permit(:name, :description, :picture, :should_delete_picture)
    end
end
```

I think that's all of them. Basically switch every `CustomCommunity` class call to `::CustomCommunity` to unnamespace it.

Comment: This can be a temporary solution, but can't figure why rails is namespacing under controller class. This is the first time I see something like this.

Comment: I get it intermittently on various projects and have never spent enough time researching to figure it out - it's not pretty but from what I can see this fix has no downsides

Comment: Problem is that I don't know why is this happening. This can only lead to new bugs.